# Switch statement inside enumeration. How to improve performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a list of items that I would like to sort using Linq OrderByDescending.
The sorting is being passed as value to a switch statement.

```
items.OrderByDescending((SomeObject)i => {
   switch(cond)
   {
      case "conditionA":
        return (float)i.MemberA;
      case "conditionB":
        return (long)i.MemberB;
      case "conditionC":
        return (int)i.MemberB;
   }})
```

My concern is regarding the performance of this loop.
Is there a way to pre-define the return value and to pass it into the loop once?

Comment: You can have default: condition that will be used if no matches. Default value can be predefined.

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem. Why are your `Member_` properties not typed correctly already?

Comment: You can't actually sort `int`s with `float`s; you'd end up casting to one or the other anyway. So you might as well compare everything as a `float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move your switch outside `OrderByDescending` method. Just define a lambda as `Func<SomeObject, float>` and assign it before linq query:

```
Func<SomeObject, float> orderBy = null;

switch (cond)
{
    case "conditionA":
        orderBy = i => (float)i.MemberA;
        break;

    case "conditionB":
        orderBy = i => (float)i.MemberB;
        break;

    default:
        orderBy = i => (int)i.MemberC;
        break;
}
```

Now you can use that lambda in your sorting

```
var res = items.OrderByDescending(orderBy);
```

If `items` is an `IQueryable` you can change `Func<...>` to `Expression<Func<...>>`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks